# NSFetchResultsController section name based on nspredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have a predicate :

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                              @"(nom BEGINSWITH[c] %@) OR (nom CONTAINS[c] %@)", _valeur, _valeur];
```

and a transient property to get result sorted by section :

```
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_mainMOC sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionIdentifier" cacheName:@"cache"];
```

I would like two sections ; first "begins with" and a second "contains".

```
- (NSString *)sectionIdentifier
{
    return ([self.nom hasPrefix:@"predicateValue"]) ? @"Begins with" : @"Contains";
}
```

How can i get the predicate value ?

The only solution I found is using arrays from fetchRequest, but I'd rather use NSFetchedResultsController (best way in my opinion).